# How can I make a discord bot send a certain message in any channel

Tags: discord.js

so I'm trying to make a discord bot (javascript) to ping my friend every time he talks. What I've tried so far are things like this from different websites:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author.id === '<@ID>') {
      msg.channel.send('<@ID>')
    }})
```

I've searched around and I can't find anything that works exept the `msg.reply` which I don't want to use because it pings the author. If anyone could help me that would be great, thanks

Comment: Can you specify what you need clearly? Do you need to send message to any channel or do you need to ping a member?

Comment: @Radnerus for example if I pinged @.discord in a random channel, I would want the bot to send a message in that same channel saying @.discord